# Getting error while inserting Customized String in xpath in Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Iam trying to locate elements in a webpage. Elements are arranged in rows. For all the rows(or elements), the common attribute is "pfobj". With the help of list interface i have listed out all the elements having attribute pfobj. While finding element with xpath iam getting error. I tried to insert srting pfobj inside xpath argument.

code for a particular element:

```
WebElement eachelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@pfobj=\"pfobj1\"]"));
```

I want to run for all elements by using loop. so i need to insert "pfobj"(which will iterate by increasing the value) in the place of "pfobj1".

I have tried the several ways but iam getting error:

```
String slash1 = "\\";

String pfobj = pfobj1;

String slash2 = "\\";

String final = slash1 + pfobj + slash2
```

Can someone please help me out with this issue

Comment: Can you share the HTML code for the elements which you are trying to locate?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
for ( WebElement element: List) { 
    if (element.getAttribute("pfobj").equals("pfobj")){
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

List is your element list

Answer (score 0):

From what I take from this question is that there are several elements in your HTML having value of `pfobj` attribute as pfobj1, pfobj2, and so on.

If you want to compare all such elements in a loop, you can do like -

```
List<WebElement> your_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@pfobj,'pfobj')]"))
int counter = 1;

for(WebElement your_element : your_list )
{
  if(your_element.getAttribute("pfobj").equals("pfobj" + counter))
   {
     //do whatever you want
   }
   counter++;
}
```